# Regular expression for specific file mask

Tags: regex

I want to have 2 regex patterns that checks files after specific file mask. The way I like to do it is written below.

Pattern 1:

1. check if the left side of `_` has 7 digits.
2. checks if the right side of `_` is numeric.
3. checks for the specified extension is there.

the input will look like this : `1234567_1.jpg`

Pattern 2:

1. check if there is 10 digits to the left of a "Space" char
2. check if there is 4 digits to the right of a "Space" char
3. check to the right side of `_` is numeric
4. check for the specified extension is there.

The input will look like this: `1234567891 1234_1.png`

As stated above this is to be used to check for a specific file mask.

i have been playing around with ideas like : ^[0-9]*[0-9].jpg$
and ^[0-9] [0-9]*[0-9].jpg$ is my first tries.

i do apologies for not providing my tries.

Comment: a) I would suggest adding what have you tried so far so we could point you in the right direction/help you better. b) As long as this is regular regex, looks like the c# tag could not be needed. c) You should consider splitting this into two different questions. Maybe when you get "pattern 1" working "pattern 2" is obvious.

Comment: Define digit, does that mean numeric or alpha numeric

Comment: Digits will be numerics and only numerics in this case.

Comment: sorry i have added some of what ive been playing around with and i removed the c# tag as you are right in that i was in a but hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest *combining* patterns with `|` (*or*):

```
    string pattern = string.Join("|",
       @"(^[0-9]{7}_[0-9]+\.jpg$)",             // 1st possibility
       @"(^[0-9]{10} [0-9]{4}_[0-9]+\.png$)");  // 2nd one

    ....

    string fileName = @"c:\myFiles\1234567_1.jpg";

    // RegexOptions.IgnoreCase - let's accept ".JPG" or ".Jpg" files 
    if (Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(fileName), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
      ...
    }
```

Let's explain the second pattern: `(^[0-9]{10} [0-9]{4}_[0-9]+\.jpg$)`

```
    ^           - anchor (string start) 
    [0-9]{10}   - 10 digits - 0-9
                - single space 
    [0-9]{4}    -  4 digits
    _           - single underscope 
    [0-9]+      -  one or more digits 
    \.png       - .png (. is escaped) 
    $           - anchor (string end)
```

Comment: it works as exactly as intended and Ashiv3r´s answer is also working answer.

Comment: I like this one 'cause of the explanation of the regex. BTW, the `' '` could also be written as `\s`

Comment: @bradbury: Sorry, but *no* `\s` means any *white space*, whci can be, say *Non-breaking space* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) and many other

Answer (score -1):

This should work for first regex:

```
\d{7}_\d*.(jpg|png)
```

This should work for second regex:

```
\d{10}\s\d{4}_\d*.(jpg|png)
```

If you want to use them together just do it like below:

```
(\d{7}_\d*.(jpg|png)|\d{10}\s\d{4}_\d*.(jpg|png))
```

In this group (jpg|png) you can just add another extensions by separating them with | (or).

You can check if it works for you at: https://regex101.com/

Cheers!